# Refused to execute script from 'myfiles.bundle.js.gz' in SharePoint Online Master page

Tags: gzip, master-pages, sharepoint-online

I have created a bundle file with  'compression-webpack-plugin'. But when I am trying to use in SharePoint online master page, it is throwing an error :

'*Refused to execute script from 'myfiles.bundle.js.gz' because its MIME type ('application/x-gzip') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.*'
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJlS2.png)

How can I use .gz file in SharePoint Online Master page?

Thanks,
Gaurav